# C# - how to create an inherited generic collection from a factory method

Tags: c#, constraints, factory, generic-collections

I am trying to write a factory method that will create a derived instance of an abstract generic collection class. Here are the base classes ...

```
abstract class ItemBase { }

abstract class CollectionBase<T> : Collection<T> where T : ItemBase, new() { }
```

...and their derived classes ...

```
class Item : ItemBase { }

class ItemCollection : CollectionBase<Item> {}
```

Now, I want a factory method that will create an ItemCollection. But note that the derived classes Item and ItemCollection are unknown to the class that contains this factory method. This is how I imagine it should be ...

```
static T CreateItemCollection<T>() where T : CollectionBase<ItemBase>, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

... and I imagine invoking it thus ...

```
var collection = CreateItemCollection<ItemCollection>();
```

But the factory method won't compile because ItemBase must have a parameterless constructor. And the invokation call refuses to believe that `ItemCollection` is derived from `CollectionBase<ItemBase>`.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ItemCollection` *isn't* derived from `CollectionBase<ItemBase>`, due to generic invariance. After all, you can add an `ItemBase` to a `CollectionBase<ItemBase>` - but you don't want that for your `ItemCollection`!

You need to make the method generic in two type parameters:

```
static T CreateItemCollection<TCollection, TItem>()
    where TCollection : CollectionBase<TItem>, new()
    where TItem : ItemBase
{
    return new TCollection();
}
```

Only the collection type needs a parameterless constructor. You'd call this with:

```
var collection = CreateItemCollection<ItemCollection, Item>();
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves my problem, even if I still can't fully understand why the compiler insists on being so strict (as commented by JaredPar below).

Comment: @Tim: As I said, because `ItemCollection` *must not* allow all the same calls as `CollectionBase<ItemBase>`. Read up on Eric Lippert's blog series about variance for more details - unfortunately I need to run now, so don't have time to chase the link.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is generic constraints, in C# 3.0, have any leeway with regards to variance.  The matching is instead fairly strict.  Since ItemCollection derives from `CollectionBase<Item>` it is not considered to be derived from `CollectionBase<ItemBase>` even though the types may *appear* to be compatible.